# Is there a way to call a value from a Text Box string from another method?

Tags: c#, windows, forms

Good day to everyone. I have a very interesting problem that has been bothering me for days now.

I am currently using Visual Studio Community to make an application, using Windows Forms, to make a PC Optimizer/Cleaner. The current problem that I have, is that I am using `system.Management` to get the values for the Physical Memory, and then use those values to make a Circular Progress Bar (counter). The issue is that I have a value in `private void Form_Load` called `textBox2.Text = (managementObject["TotalVisibleMemorySize"]).ToString();` that I want to call or pass to another method called `private void prfTimer_Tick`. You will see that in the `private void prfTimer_Tick` method is also a `textBox2.Text` value. It must read the value from the `textBox2.Text = (managementObject["TotalVisibleMemorySize"]).ToString();`method, so that it can be updated as per interval specified by the timer. Below I have posted the source code but is included in the image link as well. I know that I am asking a huge favor from you guys, but if anyone would kindly explain to me how this can be done, it would be greatly appreciated.

C# Source Code ---> https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NC1i.jpg

Windows Form   ---> https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnFxX.jpg

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Management;

namespace InClean___PC_Optimizer
{
    public partial class frmDashboard : Form
    {
        public frmDashboard()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ObjectQuery objectQuery = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem");
            ManagementObjectSearcher managementObjectSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(objectQuery);
            ManagementObjectCollection managementObjectCollection = managementObjectSearcher.Get();
            foreach (ManagementObject managementObject in managementObjectCollection)
            {
                textBox1.Text = (managementObject["FreePhysicalMemory"]).ToString();
                textBox2.Text = (managementObject["TotalVisibleMemorySize"]).ToString(); <<--- **I want this value...**
            }
        }

        private void prfTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox2.Text = (int)ramCounter.NextValue(); <<--- ... **to be called here as textBox2.Text**
            cpbCPU.Value = (int)cpuCounter.NextValue();
            cpbHDD.Value = (int)hddCounter.NextValue();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Create functions that return the required entries and use them in the `Load` and `Tick` events and elsewhere.

Comment: Do you want to refresh the memory values in `textBox2` periodically? If so you nee to move the code from the `Form_Load` into the `prfTimer_Tick` event. Also, consider renaming `textBox2` to something more meaningful. In anything but the most trivial applications, default control names get confusing very quickly.

Comment: @PatrickTucci Thank you both for answering so fast. I understand that default control names are extremely difficult to work with, but I only used it as a temporary exercise. As for the method you have described, I have already tried moving them to the `perfTimer_Tick` event, works as expected, but then the problem is that I cannot use a `.NextValue()` to get the next value to update periodically since I cannot find some good tutorials or study material on how to update the `(managementObject["FreePhysicalMemory"])` with a timer event, in this case `perfTimer_Tick`

Comment: You said that it works as expected when you move the code to `perfTimer_Tick`. Why do you need to call `NextValue()` specifically?

Comment: @PatrickTucci My mistake... I should have provided adequate information in my previous response. Please allow my some time and I will show you the source code as well as what I mean by that.

Comment: Thank you to PatrickTucci and to JQSOFT for helping me. I have finished what I wanted to do. You were of great help, if I could, I would've upvoted your comments. Here is the link of my application as an end result [link](https://imgur.com/a/qrYCMWu). You all have been of great help... Thank you !!